# xalan docbook stylesheets to generate XSL-FO: XSLT Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError): org/apache/xml/serializer/SerializerTrace

Tags: customization, xalan, docbook-xsl

Trying to run xalan to do docbook stylesheets, get the following:

```
(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError): org/apache/xml/serializer/SerializerTrace
```

Here is the shell script, `Lx.sh`

## !/bin/sh

```
export X=/home/leffstudent/docbook-xsl-1.79.1/tools/lib/


export CLASSPATH=$X/xmlresolver.jar:$X/xalan.jar:$X/xercesImpl.jar:$X/xml-apis.jar:/home/leffstudent/docbook-xsl-1.79.1/extensions/xalan27.jar:/home/leffstudent/xsl2/xsl/tools/lib/xalan/serializer.jar
java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$X org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -out $1.fo -in $1 -xsl stO.xsl -param use.extensions 1 -param default.table.width auto -param title.margin.left 0pc param insert.xref.page.number yes -param xref.with.number.and.title 0
```

---

When I run the script, I get the following error messages

```
Lx.sh test1.xml

Invalid option: param

Invalid option: insert.xref.page.number

Invalid option: yes



(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError): org/apache/xml/serializer/SerializerTrace

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org/apache/xml/serializer/SerializerTrace

    at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.doExit(Process.java:1155)

    at org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.main(Process.java:1128)
```

---

I followed the instructions on page 25 to 26 of
the wonderful book:
*DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide: Second Edition*: Sagehill Enterprises

On page 22, that listed three needed jar files:
`xalan.jar`, `xml-apis.jar`, `xercesImpl.jar`
When that did not work and I got the above error message, I added
`serializer.jar`  That did not help.

Note: I originally used saxon to do the conversion of docbook xml
to XSL-FO.  Someone suggested I try one of the other processors.
That is question number 55908387
Thus, I tried Xalan and have the above problem.

Comment: Because your are at linux box (or Mac) - can you try a xsltproc for these processing??? First step to find out the problem - try to analyze where it is situated.

Comment: #!/bin/sh

xsltproc --output $1.foa --stringparam use.extensions 0 --stringparam table.width auto  --stringparam insert.xref.page.number yes --stringparam xref.with.number.and.title 0 stO.xsl $1
; The above works with no error message.  However, still has problem in 55908387.

Comment: In your script you have `param insert.xref.page.number`. A hyphen is missing; it should be `-param insert.xref.page.number`.

Comment: Did you add the missing hyphen?

Comment: I did; no change to this problem.